# how to push elements to an array in key value format dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I was trying to create an array in JSON format so that it stores name mailId and password of the user dynamically each time a new user signs up.I was able to create for one user but i am stuck in creating a loop and also to push the element in the array var user [];.can anyone suggest me how to do this ?

```js
var user = [];
document.getElementById("sub").addEventListener("click",function store(){
 var user = {};
 user.name = document.getElementById("nme").value;
 user.emailId = document.getElementById("mail").value;
 user.password = document.getElementById("pd").value;
 console.log("user", user);
  });
```

Comment: update `var user = {}` to `var _tmp = {}` and at the end `user.push(_tmp)`

Comment: thanks a lot it worked!learned a new trick today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch the array name and then just push the user into it.

```
var users = [];
document.getElementById("sub").addEventListener("click",function store(){
    var user = {};
    user.name = document.getElementById("nme").value;
    user.emailId = document.getElementById("mail").value;
    user.password = document.getElementById("pd").value;
    console.log("user", user);
    users.push(user);
  });
```

Comment: Ideally for such small issues, you should comment.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this should do the trick.

```js
var userArray = [];
document.getElementById("sub").addEventListener("click",function store(){
    var user = {};
    user.name = document.getElementById("nme").value;
    user.emailId = document.getElementById("mail").value;
    user.password = document.getElementById("pd").value;
    userArray.push(user);
    console.log("user", user);
    console.log("userArray: ", userArray);
  });
```